# Почему return возвращает данные только из первой строки таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql

В MySQL есть таблица `main`:

```
id | order_id | sub1_arr | sub2_arr | sub3_arr | sub4_arr
 1 |        1 |  3, 6, 7 |          |       70 |         
 2 |        0 |          |          |          |         
 3 |        2 |       33 |25, 83, 9 |          |   39, 10
```

Мне нужно вывести значения всех строк из столбцов **sub1_arr**, **sub2_arr**, **sub3_arr**, **sub4_arr** *через запятую*.

Пробую вот таким образом:

```
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT `sub1_arr`,`sub2_arr`,`sub3_arr`,`sub4_arr` FROM `main`");
  while ($arr=mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($arr['sub1_arr']) {echo $arr['sub1_arr'].','};
    if ($arr['sub2_arr']) {echo $arr['sub2_arr'].','};
    if ($arr['sub3_arr']) {echo $arr['sub3_arr'].','};
    if ($arr['sub4_arr']) {echo $arr['sub4_arr'].','};
  }
```

То более-менее всё работает как надо, но в конце всегда лишняя запятая. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Но мне нужно просто вернуть (return) эти значения, а не отображать их (echo). И вот когда возвращаю (return) -- выводятся только записи из первой строки.

**Вопрос:** как оптимизировать этот запрос и выдачу результата, чтобы получить на выходе:
*3, 6, 7, 70, 33, 25, 83, 9, 39, 10*

Comment: Ну так последняя возвращается, все верно. Смотря что вам надо дальше делать.

Comment: @Cactus нужно получить на выходе: 3, 6, 7, 70, 33, 25, 83, 9, 39, 10

Comment: сделайте массив и по мере чтения таблицы добавляйте в него значения, потом этот массив возвращайте или собирайте в строку с помощью implode и возвращайте строку, если вам нужна действительно строка

Comment: @Mike нужна действительно строка. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы не возвращайте сразу, а накапливайте в строке:

```
$str = "";
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `sub1_arr`,`sub2_arr`,`sub3_arr`,`sub4_arr` FROM `main`");
while ($arr=mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($arr['sub1_arr']) {
        $str .= $arr['sub1_arr'].',';
    }
    if ($arr['sub2_arr']) {
        $str .=  $arr['sub2_arr'].',';
    }
    if ($arr['sub3_arr']) {
        $str .= $arr['sub3_arr'].',';
    }
    if ($arr['sub4_arr']) {
        $str .= $arr['sub4_arr'].',';
    }
}
return $str;
```

Проблемы такого подхода вы заметили сами -- лишняя запятая в конце. Но есть типовой обходной путь для этого:

```
$str = "";
$is_first = true;
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `sub1_arr`,`sub2_arr`,`sub3_arr`,`sub4_arr` FROM `main`");
while ($arr=mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if($is_first)
    {
        $is_first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $str .= ",";
    }
    if ($arr['sub1_arr']) {
        $str .= $arr['sub1_arr'];
    }
    if ($arr['sub2_arr']) {
        $str .=  $arr['sub2_arr'];
    }
    if ($arr['sub3_arr']) {
        $str .= $arr['sub3_arr'];
    }
    if ($arr['sub4_arr']) {
        $str .= $arr['sub4_arr'];
    }
}
return $str;
```

Я надеюсь, этот пример вам понятен, потому что правильнее делать накопление в массиве, а не в строке -- а итоговую строку уже собирать через [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) (посмотрите комментарий @Mike).

```
$res = array();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `sub1_arr`,`sub2_arr`,`sub3_arr`,`sub4_arr` FROM `main`");
while ($arr=mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($arr['sub1_arr']) {
        $res[] = $arr['sub1_arr'];
    }
    if ($arr['sub2_arr']) {
        $res[] = $arr['sub2_arr'];
    }
    if ($arr['sub3_arr']) {
        $res[] = $arr['sub3_arr'];
    }
    if ($arr['sub4_arr']) {
        $res[] = $arr['sub4_arr'];
    }
}
return implode(", ", $res);
```

Удобство `implode` заключается в том, что эта функция не поставит последнюю запятую: ваш вывод будет `3, 6, 7, 70, 33, 25, 83, 9, 39, 10,` -- а implode вернёт `3, 6, 7, 70, 33, 25, 83, 9, 39, 10`.

Это во-первых. А во-вторых, ещё в школе учат на уроках информатики, что алгоритм должен разделять шаги ввода информации, обработки и вывода.
Так вот обработку лучше делать в массиве (данные структурированы), а не в строке, а вывод уже должен быть строкой. Возможно, на таком простом примере как ваш сложно почувствовать эту выгоду, но привыкнув мыслить чётко это потом будет выручать на сложных задачах.

Дополнительно. Склеить в одну строку можно ещё на SQL-сервере. Кроме того, непонятен смысл параметров arr1 - arr4 в таблице mysql, подозреваю, что можно было бы и нормализовать таблицу дальше.

Comment: Здорово. Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ. Теперь всё стало ясно и понятно. :-)

Comment: Я проглядел одну ошибку, доберусь до компа - поправлю пока никто не заметил.